# Lookup column to task list, display only top-level items

Tags: lookup-column, task-list

I'm trying to create a lookup column to a task list, but I only want to display top-level task names in the lookup, not all the subtasks.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The native Lookup field doesn't have filter option. So you have four options.

**Option 1**

Create another task list (TaskListB) and copy the required items from original task list (TaskListA) to TaskListB. Create a workflow on TaskListA to insert/update the required new items to TaskListB. Now use TaskListB in the lookup field.

**Option 2**

Use SPServices.SPAutocomplete to implement the autocomplete feature on a textbox based on filtered data from a list. Complete documentation is [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPAutocomplete). An example code looks like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
    sourceList: "TaskList",
    sourceColumn: "Title",
    columnName: "TitleOnNewOrEditForm",
    CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq>",
    ignoreCase: true,
    numChars: 3,
    slideDownSpeed: 1000,
    debug: true
});
</script>
```

**Option 3**

Use [SharePoint filtered lookup field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) from codeplex which allows to select a list view to display filtered data in the lookup.

**Option 4**

Use a calculated column with a formula to display only top level task names and blank for others. Create a lookup on the calculated column.